# How to use REX command to extract multiple fields in splunk?

Tags: splunk

I want to be able to extract multiple fields in splunk using rex, but I am only able to extract 3 fields, then it stops working. An example of this is:

```
rex field=_raw "(?<email>\w+);(?<OrderNumber>\w+);(?<shippingStreet>\w+)"
```

That expression above shows 3 new fields in splunk which is perfect! but as soon as I add one more field, it doesn't show anything at all. is there a limit of 3 fields with rex?

Comment: There is no practical limit to the number of fields `rex` can extract.  However, we must have some sample events before we can help you.  Please provide sample data and identify what you want extracted.

Answer (score 0):

@Papaya2226
Have you tried `max_match` option of `rex` command?
use:  `max_match=0`

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.2/SearchReference/Rex#Usage

Comment: `max_match` applies if a field extraction matches more than one text in the event.  We need to see example events to know for sure.